# How to enabled multiple selection in UICollectionView using list configuration in iOS 14?

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement iOS Messages App like selection style: all the rows have a checkmark on the left in editing mode.

I am using UICollectionView with list configuration Apple introduced in iOS 14 and it seems like the implementation of multiple selection has changed.

Take `Modern Collection Views/Lists/ReorderableListViewController.swift` in [Implementing Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) for exmaple.

This was what I did:

1. Added the following code at the bottom of `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
 navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(editButtonItem, animated: true)
 collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
 collectionView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

2. Override `setEditing` method:

```swift
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    self.collectionView.isEditing = editing
}
```

3. Implement `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```swift
extension ReorderableListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      shouldBeginMultipleSelectionInteractionAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      didBeginMultipleSelectionInteractionAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(#function)
    self.collectionView.isEditing = true
  }
}
```

4. Only display reorder handle in editing mode (in `configureDataSource`):

```swift
cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator(), .reorder(displayed:.whenEditing)]
```

With these changes, I can see reoder handle being toggled when edit button is tapped. But no checkmark on the left to indicate current selected items.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false

cell.accessories = [
  .disclosureIndicator(),
  .reorder(displayed:.whenEditing),
  .multiselect()
]
```

Checkmarks will be displayed in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. Use custom accessory and place it at leading.

In `configureDataSource`'s `cellRegistration`:

```swift
let checkmark = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")           
let checkmarkImageView = UIImageView(image: checkmark)
let checkmarkViewConguration = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(
    customView: checkmarkImageView,
    placement: .leading(displayed: .whenEditing, at: { _ in 0 }))

cell.accessories = [
    .customView(configuration: checkmarkViewConguration),
    .disclosureIndicator(), 
    .reorder(displayed:.whenEditing)
]
```